# ExtJS 4 grid cell rendering control

Tags: extjs4

Ok this is a hard one to formulate for me so please forgive me if it does not really make any sense :-)

I have a situation where a plugin for a grid will put (as example) a textfield in the cell all the time (not on click or anything, instead of text it will show the text in the textfield)

Or it could be a radio button etc..

As the record changes, a column is hidden etc.. the cell will refresh/rerender itself.

I want to be able to intercept this refresh/rerender and stop it - this is ofc so my textfield will stay put.

One example is on record change, if I take the values from my textfield and change the records value - the cell will rerender itself and the textfield is gone.

Mind you the textfield added in the cell is an Ext component, so just adding a textfield to the template wont work (or anything like it), and I still would like the cell to mark itself as dirty.

I am having a HARD time finding out where to get my hook in

Comment: Have you gone through the Docs? Are you using [RowEditing](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing)? Check out the **Events** part, you may find useful `validateedit` and `canceledit`.

Comment: Nope, as I am making my own plugin I am not using RowEditing, and yes I have looked through the docs and the source files as well.

Grids are tricky bastards, they use their own view and so on (it ofc goes further than just their own views), really hard to know what does what when it comes to a grid.

One example of where I wish to hijack is when a record is changed.
Somewhere there is a listener that will make the field go dirty and rerender itself - but I can not find it, and thus I can not find what it is I need to hijack.

Comment: Have you looked at [afterrender](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-event-afterrender)? You could try to [suspendEvents](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-method-suspendEvents) too. Surf through the events, Im sure you can find something useful. I can't offer much more help without some source code, specially with a custom plugin.

Comment: Setting a record (Model Instance) as dirty programmatically won't fire any events. Those events are fired within RowEditingPlugin, like `beforeedit` and such. Have you tried overriding the renderer functions on your columns?

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  

Yes I have looked at afterrender and the events - suspendEvents was something I tried that came the closest.  

My problem is, to illustrate with a cell example that I want to be able to put an input field in place instead of a text string, and have changes in the input field (which has to be able to be configured as an xtype config object) change that records dataIndex.  If I add a listener to the input field that will set the records dataIndex - the cell will rerender itself as you have (in this case) typed your first character

Comment: Features are what I am looking into now, but also looks like a no go as it is only the template that you get to mess around with.


Think I still need to find that one place where all the cell rendering is controlled from - but cant find it :-(

Comment: I should probably point out that this is (bound by version) for extjs 4.0.7

Comment: Seems that a custom column is what I should go for - so creating my own Ext.ux.grid.column.DirectInput xtype instead - looking good so far, will keep you informed if any interest :-)

Comment: Have you tried overriding render function for that column?